# VHDL Error "Expecting constant slice on LHS"

Tags: vhdl

I wrote a code. This should insert a "1" at a position, which is determined by the binary part of a signal E_reg_sig. The bits left to the "1" should be filled up by the fractional bits of a signal E_reg_sig.

There are some special cases:

1. The position is higher than the Output signals range: then all bits are set to high
2. There are more bits left right to the "1" than E_reg_sig has fractional bits: In this case the output should be filled up with the bits from E_reg_sig's fractional part, the rest should be "0"s
3. There is less space than E_reg_sig's bits widh: In this case the code should be filled up with the Bits from E_reg_sig from MSB to LSB till there are no bits from the output to fill up anymore

```
     library ieee;
     use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    use ieee.fixed_pkg.all;
    use work.parameters.all;
    
    entity log_mvm is
      port (
    CLK:        IN  std_logic;
    E_reg: IN: ufixed(counter_log_mvm_WIDTH downto -(DATA_WIDTH_IN-2));
    F_reg: OUT: unsigned(DATA_WIDTH_IN-2 downto 0);
      );
    end log_mvm;
    architecture Behavioral of log_mvm is
    begin
    process(clk)
     variable insert_position : NATURAL;  
    if rising_edge(CLK) then
    
        insert_position:= to_integer(E_reg(E_reg'high downto 0));
    
        if insert_position > F_reg'high then
            F_reg<= (others=>'1');
        else 
            F_reg(insert_position)<='1';
         if insert_position>-1 then
            If insert_position>=(-E_reg'low) then
               F_reg(insert_position-1 downto insert_position+E_reg'low)<=unsigned(E_reg(-1 downto E_reg'low));
            else  
                F_reg(insert_position-1 downto 0)<=unsigned(E_reg(-1 downto -insert_position));
          END if;
          END IF;
        end if;
       
        END IF;
        END IF;
        end process;
    end Behavioral;
```

`DATA_WIDTH_IN` is defined as natural with the value 8

This codes works in simulation fine, but for synthezise, there is the error "[Synth 8-7138] Expecting constant slice on LHS" on part  `F_reg(insert_position-1 downto 0)<=unsigned(E_reg(-1 downto -insert_position));`

How to avoid this

I am using VHDL 2008 with Vivad0 2021

Comment: Your code has syntax errors: `clk` is missing from the design as a signal or a port. There is no declaration of `e_reg` or `f_reg`. The synth error you specify is not a VHDL error - it is a limitation of the tool you are using - many require constant ranges when slicing arrays. Also note that `if insert_position>-1 then` is always true, as a natural starts at 0.

Comment: Thank you . By translating my program to a minimal example, this mistakes occur. 
I correct it. 
I am using VHDL 2008 with Vivado 2021

Comment: IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 RTL Synthesis (withdrawn, lack of vendor participation) 8.6.5 Slice name "For a discrete range that appears as part of a slice name, the bounds of the discrete range shall be specified directly or indirectly as static values belonging to an integer type."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to work with a loop:

```
for i in F_reg'range loop
    if i<=insert_position-1 then
        F_reg(i) <= E_reg(i-insert_position);
    end if;
end loop;
```

Comment: Thank you! WOuldnt it not be more hardware and timing -efficient to include the if statement in the for loop, because than we are not doing so much loops? Or is vivado automatically optimzing that?

Comment: synthesis will unroll all loops for the maximum range. conditional Loops do not exist in hardware.